# tv-tab-container js for working tabs with closure library

Tags: javascript, navigation, dom-events, google-closure, google-tv

I have a project that involves using the Google TV UI Closure library for keyboard/d-pad navigation. I'm using the code copied right from Google's appspot tvui demos for a tv-tab-container

```
<div class="tv-tab-container tv-container-vertical">
  <div class="tv-tab-container-bar tv-container-horizontal">
    // Tab bar components.
  </div>
  <div class="tv-tab-container-content tv-container-horizontal">
    // Content components.
  </div>
</div>
```

I was under the impression that the closure library would handle changing the content of the tabs, but it doesn't. Does anybody know the Javascript required to make the tabs function? I don't quite understand the closure library's event handling with the tv-tab-container-bar tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after all this I ended up just writing my own event listeners for keyboard left and right when focused on the tv-tab-container, and used the setFocusedComponent() to change the tab-content accordingly by using dynamically created div id's. I'm still not entirely sure why every other tv-ui component works for me but the tv-tab-container, but this mimics the same behavior that I was after

```
function updateTabContent(content, tab)
{
//sets the correct tab and content to be focused and visible
var allContentDivs = $('.tab-demo-content').hide();
var contentToShow = $('#'+content);
contentToShow.show();

var elementToFocus = goog.dom.getElement(content);
var componentToFocus = tv.ui.getComponentByElement(elementToFocus);
tv.ui.Document.getInstance().setFocusedComponent(componentToFocus);

elementToFocus = goog.dom.getElement('tab' + tab);
componentToFocus = tv.ui.getComponentByElement(elementToFocus);
tv.ui.Document.getInstance().setFocusedComponent(componentToFocus)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The demo of tab container at tvuidemos.appspot.com/ works well.  First of all your HTML needs to be enhanced like the following with content component:

tab 1tab 2tab 3tab 4
  
  
    content 1
    content 2
    content 3
    content 4

Secondly you may need to include more js files than just the tab_container.js.  This link lists the dependency you might need:

http://tvuidemos.appspot.com/static/tv-ui/deps.js

If you have a public URL to share for your tab container sample, it might be easier to pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: Here's a zip of the tab demo I'm trying to get to work, best I can do for right now. I'm using an uncompiled version of closure right now http://www.filedropper.com/tabtest

Comment: I looked at your HTML in the tabtest. Yours is different from the sample code.  CSS class tags are hard coded in JS for Closure so you have to use the exact one as prescribed.  I'll add more comments in a longer answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough detail in your question to allow for any reasonable answer. Please revise your question with more detail and code along with what you are trying to achieve.

Edit 1:
Again, there is no information in the question you are asking. Your question is "why is my code not working" but you have not provided access to your code. Statements like "it looks correct but it's not functional" add no insight into why you cannot get your code to work. My suggestion is this: post your code somewhere like github and provide a link (all relevant files to reproduce your issue) or host your code somewhere in a running state such that it can be looked at on a Google TV.

Comment: Alright. Check out the "Tab Container" demo here http://tvuidemos.appspot.com/#. I'm trying to replicate that. I'm using the googletv closure library for keyboard navigation. I copied and pasted the html and css for that tab container, and it looks correct but isn't functional. As in when you select each tab, the content doesn't change. My question is if anybody here knows how to make the tv-tab-container functional so that the content div changes when a tab is selected/focused. I need to add the "tv-container-selected-child" class to the appropriate div when it's corresponding tab is selected

Comment: Also, I've included the script tv-ui/tab_container.js from the demo, the content div still doesn't change

Comment: Ok I can see now what has happened. You cannot just copy over the js files as you have - the deps.js has relative paths associated with it and as such your page is not even loading the closure libs. You either need to duplicate the entire relative library path to match what you copied from or you need to recompile the closure source to match your project settings. See: https://developers.google.com/closure/

Comment: I haven't yet looked into how to use the closure compiler, I figured I'd take a look once my projects near completion. Would you mind telling me what the proper relative path would be in the current tv-deps? It seems correct to me, and I don't get any errors claiming a false path.

Comment: It will be a world of pain as all the source files get modified using the closure compiler. If you open in the tv-deps file and remove ../../../../ from all the path headers then you will see the issues with your approach. If you are going to use the closure code you need to understand how it works - otherwise you will spend a lot of time trying to get things working.

Comment: Yes this is my first project with closure so I'm still learning everything as I go, but I'd really like to get a good understanding of it. I tried removing the ../../ from each line and I got an error for invalid path, so that just leads me to believe that the previous path was correct because it didn't give an error. Would running depswriter again fix this? I really appreciate all the help btw, taking on closure blindly hasn't been an easy task.

Comment: Ok looking a little closer it would seem you set the id of all the tabs to 'tab1' - and all the content divs have the same id of 'content1' - For an explanation of how to do tabbing with closure - look here: http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/11/16/googe-closure-create-tabs-component-goog-ui-tabpane/

Comment: The article you linked suggests markup using a semantic html structure which contradicts the code structure suggested on the googletv appspot demos, from my original post

Comment: One a side note, is there a way to explicitly tell closure to change it's currently focused component within a container? As in a way to tell closure to change it's "tv-container-selected-child tv-component-focused" to a div of my choice by code? If this were possible I could very easily make this tab container work

Answer (score 0):

The Tab Container at this demo: http://tvuidemos.appspot.com/# is given as follows.

< div class="tv-tab-container tv-container-vertical">
  < div class="tv-tab-container-bar tv-container-horizontal demo-tab-bar">
    < div class="demo-tab tv-component">tab 1< /div>< div class="demo-tab tv-component">tab 2< /div><div class="demo-tab tv-component">tab 3< /div>< div class="demo-tab tv-component">tab 4< /div>
  < /div>
  < div class="tv-tab-container-content tv-tab-container-focus-attractor tv-container-horizontal demo-tab-content-container">
    < div class="tab-demo-content tv-component">content 1< /div>
...
  < /div>
< /div>

< /div>
< /div>

Notice the tv-tab-container needs to be there because it's used in http://tvuidemos.appspot.com/static/tv-ui/tab_container.js file.

Comment: the tv-tab-container is in my original post, as well as the zip i posted in comments. i copied the structure directly from the tvuidemos.appspot source, I even kept their markup classes the same